# Reason Phrase charset

Tags: http, character-encoding

What is the charset used for http Reason Phrase?

If I use special char `è` (utf8 encoded) chrome works well, but Firefox show "Ã©".

I don't find anything about that on reference http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The production in RFC 2616 is

```
Reason-Phrase  = *<TEXT, excluding CR, LF>
```

and the RFC explains: “The TEXT rule is only used for descriptive field contents and values that are not intended to be interpreted by the message parser. Words of *TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than ISO-8859-1 only when encoded according to the rules of RFC 2047”. This suggests that the implied encoding is ISO-8859-1, so Firefox would be right here.